# gunicorn and gevent not using all resources

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

Gunicorn and gevent not using the resources I'm telling it to. When I tell gunicorn to use one worker, it uses one worker and maximizes one core. If I tell it to use 4 workers it spreads ONE core along 4 different workers. I want one worker to have one CPU. Same problem when i use the `--threads` option.

I have a NER engine that loads x MB of GPU memory for the model. Now i want to maximize the number of requests to that service. As of right now, my best result is with `gunicorn -t 120 -w 4 -k gevent --threads 12 -b 0.0.0.0:8980 script:app` which results in ~ 2.1k requests/min. 
When inspecting the resource usage, it seems to use a lot when loading the model, as expected. But when actually calling the API, it seems to not use much at all.

[Loading model.](https://ibb.co/Wk5cHKs)

[Calling the API.](https://ibb.co/sJD1KWx)

I want to increase the throughput. Increasing the number of threads and workers doesn't seem to matter..

P.s I'm running on a power machine, so resources aren't problem.

On a side note, the best possible thing would be to have one worker which actually loads the model, and then several workers that uses that model. One of the big problems at the moment is that I'm running out of GPU memory when i have +12 worker due to every worker having to load the model in the GPU memory. Is there any way to do this? If I understand `gevent` correct, it is supposed to take care of that?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
Just noticed that gunicorn did nothing at all. I get the same results running the service without gunicorn. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Usually linux-based systems show CPU utilization not relatively to total cores, but a single core. So on multicore systems utilization per process may be more than 100% and 100% means that _only a single core_ is fully utilized. I'd advise you to log CPU utilization with a tool that shows a CPU id and then return to your question with results.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Which is why I'm guessing it never actually uses more than one core. 
CPU power isn't an issue. I have measured that as well, and never goes above 10% when actually running the script. Every model requires a bit of memory since its stored in the GPU memory, but I still have a lot of memory left to use.

Comment: Are you sure CPU is actually your constraint? If you're being limited by some other factor, either IO speed or the speed of your GPU, then it may be that you can't keep more than one core busy 100% of the time anyway.

Comment: _never actually uses more than one core_ 100% CPU utilization (per process) x 4 gunicorn workers means that 4 CPU cores are unilized.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Any ideas on why i get better results when having only one instance of the service than when I have 4x of the same instance? Shouldn't Gunicorn acts as a LoadBalancer for the 4x instances and make sure that they all go at full speed? In my test i send ~16k request/min, but only get ~2.3k/min back. Again, that's with 1 instance. Increasing the workers to 4 should multiply the throughput by 4, right? Or have I totally misunderstood Gunicorn?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same issue adding gunicorn workers doesnt seem to improve my case at all. Similar use case with NER's and prediction models.

Comment: so, to maximise throughput and resource-usage, using a single unicorn worker on a machine like t2.small(1 vCPU, 1GB mem) or t2.micro(1 vCPU, 2GB mem) in k8s might solve these issues!!!

Comment: @t3ng1l Have you figured out the solution for this? I'm also most probably in the same issue.

Comment: @Garvit I can't remember if I'm being honest, it was too long ago.. Sorry.